# Playa - Next / Previous Sibling

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, next-prev

Is there a way in Playa, or by hacking Playa, to select the previous or next sibling to the current entry? I can't find anything in the docs.

Ideally, something like this (assuming we use the existing P&T tag)

```
{exp:playa:siblings entry_id="5"}

   {previous}
        <a href="{path=template/{url_title}}">< Previous</a>
   {/previous}

   {next}
        <a href="{path=template/{url_title}}">Next ></a>
   {/next}

{/exp:playa:siblings}
```

Or as it's own tag:

```
{exp:playa:prev_sibling entry_id="5"}
        <a href="{path=template/{url_title}}">Previous ></a>
{/exp:playa:prev_sibling}

{exp:playa:next_sibling entry_id="5"}
        <a href="{path=template/{url_title}}">Next ></a>
{/exp:playa:next_sibling}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm working on the same issue. Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This add-on may be worth a try:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/advanced-prev-next-entry

Version 1.2.0 added a tiny bit of Playa support. I'm not sure it will suit your needs or not though, take a look just the same; if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I suspect the best way to do this may be to pass sibling id's using {exp:playa:sibling_ids} ( http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/sibling_ids.html ) to the native EE next / previous entry tags - {exp:channel:next_entry} and {exp:channel:prev_entry} ( http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_linking.html ).